# AnyChart. How to add|remove markers?

Tags: javascript, anychart

Anybody know how to add|remove custom markers from series in AnyChart JS?
I cant find it  in documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you mean series markers. To turn them on and off use markers() method, available for all series except the markers series itself.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/85Lbeu8p/1/

```
var markers = series.markers();
markers.enabled(true);
markers.fill('gold');
```

Method reference: https://api.anychart.com/7.8.0/anychart.core.radar.series.Line#markers